# Secure Protocol

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation

How to show there is no secure protocol to compute OR?

I need to know the mathematical proof of this statement. I am understanding this statement using the matrix representation of $f(x,y)$ but unable to think mathematically. I only need a few hints to prove it.

Comment: Hint: If you know one input, what can you deduce about the other from the result?

Comment: Secure protocol with which constraints? Two parties? Honest-but-curious? Information-theoretic security? (because 3-party single-corruption information-theoretic OR can be computed securely; even 2-party OR can be computed securely under cryptographic assumptions, so the exact setup clearly matters here).

Comment: In my question I am asking about secure protocol in two parties. But the statement you have written i.e. "2-party OR can be computed securely under cryptographic assumption". Kindly explain 'how' and what are those cryptographic assumptions? Till now I have read there is no secure protocol to compute OR. Because this is not a decomposable function and it contains the OR-minor(if I will use the theorem that is "A function is securely computable in presence of passive adversary iff it is decomposable).